# How to get previous state from Router_Cancel in ngrx?

Tags: redux, angular5, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store-4.0

I was trying to restrict the user from navigating away from the current page by using `CanDeactivate` (if form is dirty and not saved). By the time we click on any link, `Router_Navigation` event is getting called and it is updating the router state in store and if I cancel the page navigation on modal pop up (from can deactivate), `Router_Cancel` event is being called, but the current router state is not getting updated (it’s still pointing to other page).

I saw this in `ngrx` documentation:

> ROUTER_CANCEL and ROUTER_ERROR contain the store state before the
>   navigation. Use the previous state to restore the consistency of the
>   store.

Can someone please help me on how to get previous state from `Router_cancel` Action.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by creating an applicationRouter state to maintain current and previous routes, whenever ngrx router dispatches a ROUTER_NAVIGATION Event i am listening to it and updating my applicationRouterState.

At each point applicationRouter will have only two router events (current and previous state).

and whenever Router_Cancel is triggered i am toggling the previous router and current router state.

PFB, the soln:

```
@Effect()
    navigationListener$ = this.actions$.ofType('ROUTER_NAVIGATION')
        .pipe(
            switchMap((routerNavigationAction: RouterNavigationAction<RouterDefinition>) => {
                return of(routerNavigationAction).pipe(
                    withLatestFrom(this._routerNavigationData$),
                    map(([action, routerNavData]: [RouterNavigationAction<RouterDefinition>, RouterState]) => {
                        // TODO: Move this logic to Reducer
                        if (!(routerNavData.currentRouter && routerNavData.currentRouter.url
                            && routerNavData.previousRouter && routerNavData.previousRouter.url)) {
                            routerNavData.previousRouter = routerNavData.currentRouter =  action.payload.routerState;
                        } else {
                            routerNavData.previousRouter = routerNavData.currentRouter;
                            routerNavData.currentRouter = action.payload.routerState;
                        }
                        return new fromActions.MaintainPrevCurrRouterStateAction(routerNavData);
                    })
                );
            })
        );
```

And this is my state object:

```
export interface RouterDefinition {
    url: string;
    queryParams: Params;
    params: Params;
    segments: string[];
}
export interface RouterState {
    currentRouter: RouterDefinition;
    previousRouter: RouterDefinition;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I use a `ngrx/effect` to store the latest two `ROUTER_NAVIGATION` actions, and re-dispatch the previous one when I get a `ROUTER_CANCEL` or `ROUTER_ERROR` so that the router state is completely restored.

```
@Injectable()
export class RouterEffects {
    private previousRouterNavigationAction: RouterNavigationAction<
        RouterStateUrl
    >;
    private currentRouterNavigationAction: RouterNavigationAction<
        RouterStateUrl
    >;

    @Effect({ dispatch: false })
    save$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(ROUTER_NAVIGATION),
        switchMap((action: RouterNavigationAction<RouterStateUrl>) => {
            this.previousRouterNavigationAction = this.currentRouterNavigationAction;
            this.currentRouterNavigationAction = { ...action };
            return Observable.empty();
        })
    );

    @Effect()
    load$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(ROUTER_CANCEL, ROUTER_ERROR),
        switchMap(action => Observable.of(this.previousRouterNavigationAction))
    );

    constructor(private actions$: Actions) {}
}
```

Comment: This is a hack solution because when I re-dispatch the previous `ROUTER_NAVIGATION` action from this effect, there isn't an actual navigation.

Comment: Hack or not, it does work and I found it easier to understand than other solutions.  I can't believe ngrx doesn't do this for you.  Completely goes against what you would expect.

Comment: That is great, you def. saved my day